# Produce randomly-generated pronouncable names

Tags: beginner, rust

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct ResourceName {
    chars: [u8; 9],
    size: u8,
}

impl ResourceName {
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.chars[0..usize::from(self.size)]) }
    }

    fn generate(&mut self, rng: &mut UnityRNG) {
        const VOWELS: &[u8; 5] = b"AEIOU";
        const CONSONANTS: &[u8; 21] = b"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

        let pairs = rng.int_range(0, 3) + 2;
        self.size = 0;
        fn add_char(out: &mut ResourceName, rng: &mut UnityRNG, letters: &[u8]) {
            out.chars[usize::from(out.size)] = letters[rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
            out.size += 1;
        }
        for _ in 0..pairs {
            if rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            } else {
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                    add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                } else {
                    add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                    add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                }
            }
        }
        if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
            if VOWELS.contains(&self.chars[usize::from(self.size) - 1]) {
                add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
            } else {
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code generates a pronounceable (or pronounceable-ish) random name. I am re-implementing code that exists elsewhere, so it must perform this *exact* sequence of sequence of steps; I have no leeway in how the algorithm works. I chose a slightly unconventional representation (fixed-size `[u8]` and a u8 size) because I need to generate a *lot* of these, quickly: It's important that no heap allocation be on the hot path.

Aside from general style improvement, I'm particularly interested if there's a way to improve the situation with the `add_char` helper function. In C++ I would use a lambda and capture `self` (this) and `rng`, but that's not an option here because of the borrow checker. C++ also has macros as an option, and I looked into that but the different scopes of identifiers in `macro_rules!` foiled me.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to speed up your code **by 5-10%** by unrolling the loop:

```rust
    fn generate(&mut self, rng: &mut UnityRNG) {
        const VOWELS: &[u8; 5] = b"AEIOU";
        const CONSONANTS: &[u8; 21] = b"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

        let pairs = rng.int_range(0, 3) + 2;
        self.size = 0;
        #[inline]
        fn add_char(out: &mut ResourceName, rng: &mut UnityRNG, letters: &[u8]) {
            out.chars[usize::from(out.size)] = letters[rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
            out.size += 1;
        }
        for _ in 0 .. pairs - 1 {
            if rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            } else {
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                    add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                } else {
                    add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                    add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                }
            }
        }
        if rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
            }
        } else {
            if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                }
            } else {
                add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT: Improved a bit the situation with add_char calls without any performance loss**

```rust
impl ResourceName {
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.chars[0..usize::from(self.size)]) }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn add_chars<'a, T: AsRef<[&'a [u8]]>>(&mut self, rng: &mut UnityRNG, chars: T) {
        for &letters in chars.as_ref() {
            self.chars[usize::from(self.size)] = letters[rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
            self.size += 1;
        }
    }

    fn generate(&mut self, rng: &mut UnityRNG) {
        const VOWELS: &[u8] = b"AEIOU";
        const CONSONANTS: &[u8] = b"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

        let pairs = rng.int_range(0, 3) + 2;
        self.size = 0;
        for _ in 0 .. pairs - 1 {
            if rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
                self.add_chars(rng, [VOWELS, VOWELS]);
            } else {
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars(rng, [VOWELS, CONSONANTS]);
                } else {
                    self.add_chars(rng, [CONSONANTS, VOWELS]);
                }
            }
        }
        if rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
            self.add_chars(rng, [VOWELS, VOWELS]);
            if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                self.add_chars(rng, [CONSONANTS]);
            }
        } else {
            if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                self.add_chars(rng, [VOWELS, CONSONANTS]);
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars(rng, [VOWELS]);
                }
            } else {
                self.add_chars(rng, [CONSONANTS, VOWELS]);
                if rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars(rng, [CONSONANTS]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

A solution that further improves add_char calls. If you have to carry multiple pieces of state together for a while, like in your situation, it's best to add a record type rather than use anonymous functions. You may add methods on that type like I did below. This is probably what you were looking for. It is **10% slower**. If you flatten the record, the performance might come back. That is left to check for you if you wish.

```rust
struct ResourceNameWithRng<'a, 'b> {
    resource_name: &'a mut ResourceName,
    rng: &'b mut UnityRNG,
}

impl<'a, 'b> ResourceNameWithRng<'a, 'b> {
    #[inline]
    fn add_chars<'c, T: AsRef<[&'c [u8]]>>(&mut self, chars: T) {
        for &letters in chars.as_ref() {
            self.resource_name.chars[usize::from(self.resource_name.size)] = letters[self.rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
            self.resource_name.size += 1;
        }
    }

    fn generate(&mut self) {
        const VOWELS: &[u8] = b"AEIOU";
        const CONSONANTS: &[u8] = b"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

        let pairs = self.rng.int_range(0, 3) + 2;
        self.resource_name.size = 0;
        for _ in 0 .. pairs - 1 {
            if self.rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
                self.add_chars([VOWELS, VOWELS]);
            } else {
                if self.rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars([VOWELS, CONSONANTS]);
                } else {
                    self.add_chars([CONSONANTS, VOWELS]);
                }
            }
        }
        if self.rng.next_float() < 0.1 {
            self.add_chars([VOWELS, VOWELS]);
            if self.rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                self.add_chars([CONSONANTS]);
            }
        } else {
            if self.rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                self.add_chars([VOWELS, CONSONANTS]);
                if self.rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars([VOWELS]);
                }
            } else {
                self.add_chars([CONSONANTS, VOWELS]);
                if self.rng.next_float() < 0.5 {
                    self.add_chars([CONSONANTS]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, very nice! The downside is that there's a lot more duplication... I wonder if I could use a flag and rustc would be smart enough to do this optimization for me. At the minimum, it would probably extract much of the speedup without so much duplicated code.

Comment: Re: ResourceNameWithRng, thank you, I see the solution now. To satisfy the borrow checker, you need to encapsulate the state in a *single* place that outlives the sub-uses, so by making a struct we "hoist" the borrows to a higher scope. I agree it's not worth it here, but the technique is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is joining those two `next_float`s per pair:

```rust
for _ in 0..pairs {
    match rng.int_range(0, 20) {
        0 ..= 1 => {
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
        }
        2 ..= 10 => {
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
            add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
        }
        11 ..= 19 => {
            add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
            add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
        }
        _ => unreachable!()
    }
}
```

Next, we may change this:

```rust
if rng.int_range(0, 2) == 0 {
    if VOWELS.contains(&self.chars[usize::from(self.size) - 1]) {
        add_char(self, rng, CONSONANTS);
    } else {
        add_char(self, rng, VOWELS);
    }
}
```

Helper functions are okay. You may want to annotate them with `#[inline]` or `#[inline(always)]`, so that they behave like a macro, but the compiler will probably inline them without any additional hints.

The best I could come up with is a precomputation of all possible letter pairs. Do you have this kind of leeway?

```rust
fn combine_two(pairs: &mut Vec<[u8; 2]>, first: &[u8], second: &[u8], times: usize) {
    for _ in 0 .. times {
        for &a in first {
            pairs.extend(second.iter().map(|&b| [a, b]));
        }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref PAIRS: Vec<[u8; 2]> = {
        let mut pairs = vec![];
        combine_two(&mut pairs, VOWELS, VOWELS, 2);
        combine_two(&mut pairs, VOWELS, CONSONANTS, 9);
        combine_two(&mut pairs, CONSONANTS, VOWELS, 9);
        pairs
    };
}
```

NOTE: the code is untested.

The result is **3x speed improvement**.

Result:

````rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

use std::ops::Index;

use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use rand::{Rng, thread_rng, rngs::ThreadRng, rngs::SmallRng, SeedableRng};

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct ResourceName {
    chars: [u8; 9],
    size: u8,
}

pub struct UnityRNG { rng: SmallRng }

const VOWELS: &[u8; 5] = b"AEIOU";
const CONSONANTS: &[u8; 21] = b"BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

impl UnityRNG {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        UnityRNG { rng: SmallRng::from_entropy() }
    }

    pub fn int_range(&mut self, start: i32, end: i32) -> i32 {
        self.rng.gen_range(start .. end)
    }

    pub fn next_float(&mut self) -> f64 {
        self.rng.gen()
    }
}

fn combine_two(pairs: &mut Vec<[u8; 2]>, first: &[u8], second: &[u8], times: usize) {
    for _ in 0 .. times {
        for &a in first {
            pairs.extend(second.iter().map(|&b| [a, b]));
        }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref PAIRS: Vec<[u8; 2]> = {
        let mut pairs = vec![];
        combine_two(&mut pairs, VOWELS, VOWELS, 2);
        combine_two(&mut pairs, VOWELS, CONSONANTS, 9);
        combine_two(&mut pairs, CONSONANTS, VOWELS, 9);
        pairs
    };
}

#[inline]
fn add_two_chars<'a>(out: impl Iterator<Item=&'a mut u8>, letters: [u8; 2]) {
    for (src, dst) in letters.iter().zip(out) {
        *dst = *src;
    }
}

#[inline]
fn add_rand_one_char<'a>(mut out: impl Iterator<Item=&'a mut u8>, rng: &mut UnityRNG, letters: &[u8]) {
    let add = letters[rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
    if let Some(dst) = out.next() {
        *dst = add;
    }
}

#[inline]
fn add_rand_two_chars<'a>(out: impl Iterator<Item=&'a mut u8>, rng: &mut UnityRNG, letters: &[[u8; 2]]) {
    let add = letters[rng.int_range(0, letters.len() as i32) as usize];
    add_two_chars(out, add);
}

impl ResourceName {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ResourceName { chars: [0; 9], size: 0 }
    }

    pub fn to_str(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.chars[0..usize::from(self.size)]) }
    }

    pub fn generate(&mut self, rng: &mut UnityRNG) {
        let mut iter = self.chars.iter_mut();
        let pairs = rng.int_range(0, 3) + 2;
        for _ in 0 .. pairs - 1 {
            add_rand_two_chars(&mut iter, rng, &PAIRS[..]);
        }
        if rng.int_range(0, 2) == 0 {
            let mut out = [0; 2];
            add_rand_two_chars(out.iter_mut(), rng, &PAIRS[..]);
            let ary = if VOWELS.contains(&out[1]) { &CONSONANTS[..] } else { &VOWELS[..] };
            add_two_chars(&mut iter, out);
            add_rand_one_char(&mut iter, rng, ary);
        }
        self.size = 9 - iter.as_slice().len() as u8;
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let mut name = ResourceName::new();
        let mut rng = UnityRNG::new();
        name.generate(&mut rng);
        let result = name.to_str();
        assert_eq!(PAIRS.len(), 9700);
        assert_eq!(result, "ABC");
    }

    use test::{Bencher, black_box};

    #[bench]
    fn bench_resource_name(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let mut name = ResourceName::new();
        let mut rng = UnityRNG::new();

        b.iter(|| {
            name.generate(&mut rng);
            black_box(name.to_str());
        });
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't perform any of these optimizations, because as I said I must perform those *exact* steps. int_range() is a different operation than next_float(), it has the same *probabilities* but doesn't land on the same values for the same states of the RNG.

Comment: @D0SBoots Then it's hard or impossible to improve on your code. Inline code with macros doesn't help, because add_char is getting inlined already.

Comment: Ultimately I wasn't looking for *speed* improvements, but rather style improvements. :) But I'm guessing from the response that the style was OK from the start.

Comment: @D0SBoots Hard to improve on style when the code is readable. Your only trouble is two quite long lines, but that's just nitpicking. Why are you intent on looking for better style?

Comment: This is (part of) the first thing I've written in Rust, in my experience being new to a language means you aren't fully aware of all the tools and idioms yet, so there may be "obvious" ways of doing something that you miss. Also (as I said in the question) the situation with having to repeat myself in the args of `add_char` was vexing, I know how to solve this in basically any other language but not Rust.

Comment: @D0SBoots Ah, I see. You want to carry two pieces of state (ResourceName and UnityRNG) together across multiple method calls. Updated my second answer with two solutions. I did not see any problem with your code, because usually it's okay to repeat yourself a bit in code and not overdo the Don't Repat Yourself rule for the sake of dubious code clarity. (By the way, nitpick: UnityRNG should be renamed to UnityRng as Rust naming conventions suggest)